# Submenus of Navigation Links Does Not Stay When Hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this navbar with links and when hovered, the submenus appear. My problem is that in my jQuery code, I only let the .nav-list show and hide upon hovering. How do we make the submenus appear until a link has been clicked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find('.nav-list').hide();
  $('#main-navigation > li').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find(".nav-list").show();
    },
    function() {
    $(this).find(".nav-list").hide();
    }
  );
  $(".nav-title").click(function() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww > 640) {
      $(this).next().toggle();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="main-navigation">
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-title">학교소개</a>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#">인사말</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">규정</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">캠퍼스 소개</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">찾아오시는 길</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-title">전공안내</a>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#">체육학</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">전공소개</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">졸업 후 진로</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">교육 프로그램</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">교수소개</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-title">입학안내</a>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#">모집요강</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">원서접수</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">입학문의</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-title">학사안내</a>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#">학점은행제</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">학사제도</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav-title">커뮤니티</a>
    <div class="nav-list">
      <ul class="header-list">
        <li><a href="#">공지사항</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">서식자료실</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I wanted my output to happen is when I hover on a link, submenus will appear and when I want to click a submenu, The submenu links will stay until it is not hovered anymore.

Comment: Can you share the complete code with css as issue could be anywhere... or set up fiddle for same

Comment: Its seems code itself is incomplete check codepen i get error in js https://codepen.io/kashmiriguide/pen/aXzWLO

Comment: here @Learning -> https://codepen.io/alexdeveloperdeneris/pen/omgwNe CSS has been added

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top: 36px;` from the CSS below:

```css
.nav-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    min-width: 125px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    /* margin-top: 36px; */ 
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: ah yes, but I wanted to make the .nav-list to be displayed below the header. inline with the bottom border of the header. is it possible? @Xenio Gracias

Answer (score 0):

If you want your sub-menu to be displayed until you hover any other menu list you have to modify your JavaScript

```
 $('#main-navigation > li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find(".nav-list").show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find(".nav-list").hide();
        }
    );
```

some thing like below,

```
 $('#main-navigation > li').hover(
        function(){
            $('.nav-list').hide();
            $(this).find(".nav-list").show();
        }
    );
```

[working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/xc95gvsf/13/)

## Updated:

I assume that you are using absolute positioning for you sub-menu and positioned far away from your menu. This triggers hover out even before you reach the sub-menu. try some timeout which the display for a while so that you can reach the sub-menu

```
var HoverTimeOut;
  $(this).find('.nav-list').hide();
    $('#main-navigation > li').hover(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(HoverTimeOut);
            //$(this).find(".nav-list").show();
            $('.nav-list').hide();
            $(this).find(".nav-list").show();
        },
        function(){
            HoverTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.nav-list').hide();
          }, 200)
            
        }
    );
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/xc95gvsf/52/)

Comment: how do we make the submenu disappear when mouse pointer is pointing at any part of the website and not just the next menu list? that is what I want my navigation menu would do.

Comment: you mean clicking out at any part of your website or moving the mouse. If it's moving the mouse. can you explain the difference between what you wanted and what you initially did?

Comment: what I did is when I hover my mouse to the navlinks, the submenu appears and when I put away the mouse pointer, submenu disappears. Because the display of my submenu is a little bit below from the nav-links. i wanted it to stick just below the nav-bar and when I put away my mouse, the sub menu disappears when I wanted my submenu still visible so that I can click on my submenus too. can you picture out what I'm saying? @Anto

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking on @Xenio Gracias answer a little bit, instead of removing margin-top just change margin to auto

```
.nav-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    min-width: 125px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```